Sphinx error: "plantuml command 'https://localhost:1234/img/' cannot be run" when using remote PlantUML server
Question:
I am trying to configure Sphinx to use a remote PlantUML server. My server is deployed at https://localhost:1234/img/. I have configured conf.py to use this server for generating diagrams.
Here’s what I added to my conf.py:
extensions = ['sphinxcontrib.plantuml']

plantuml = 'https://localhost:1234/img/'
plantuml_output_format = 'png'

...

When I try to build the documentation, I get the following error:
plantuml command 'https://localhost:1234/img/' cannot be run

I understand that Sphinx expects a path to a local PlantUML jar file, but I want to use a remote server. How do I properly configure Sphinx to work with a remote PlantUML server?
Additional Information:

I am using Sphinx version 7.2.6
The PlantUML server is deployed using Docker and is accessible via the given URL
using jar extension is not allowed by ci policy in my company

How can I configure Sphinx to generate diagrams via a remote PlantUML server?

sphinxcontrib.plantuml does not support using a Plantuml server. See https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/plantuml/issues/21.
